# maven: (use -source 5 or higher to enable static import declarations)

Tags: java, maven-2

How can I use source 5?
I tried

```
mvn -source 5 test
```

but it didn't work :-)

When I compile the file by javac, everything works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to configure the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

EDIT: Changed example to use latest version of the plugin.

Comment: note that you don't have to specify the version of the plugin.