# Error calling "mvn install" in maven due to use of generics and annotations

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [maven: (use -source 5 or higher to enable static import declarations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451268/maven-use-source-5-or-higher-to-enable-static-import-declarations)

What do I need to do to get around this error in Maven (there's more, I just copied the top).

**A key message seems to be:**

> could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable
>   annotations)

but I tried adding `-source 5` to the command and it didn't recognize it.  Do I need to edit a configuration file somewhere to state a Java version to use or something along those lines?

**Here's the error:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

C:\SVN-atx-Ingestion\branches\atx-ingestion\src\main\java\com\somecompany\eikon\atx\ingestion\database\atxAtomickosXaDataSource.java:[115,4] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3

could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
C:\SVN-atx-Ingestion\branches\atx-ingestion\src\main\java\com\somecompany\eikon\atx\ingestion\database\atxAtomickosNonXaDataSource.java:47: error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
        @Override
         ^

could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
C:\SVN-atx-Ingestion\branches\atx-ingestion\src\main\java\com\somecompany\eikon\atx\ingestion\database\XaDatabase.java:29: error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
        private final Map<String,atxAtomickosXaDataSource> map =
```

Comment: You need to configure the compiler plugin as described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451268/maven-use-source-5-or-higher-to-enable-static-import-declarations)

Comment: What does your pom look like?

Comment: Duplicates the question mentioned by @Rob Harrop

Comment: Yup, you're right.  I didn't see that when I searched originally.  I'll close after I'm sure my problem goes away when I try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this I think:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
             ...
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.6</source>
                                        <target>1.6</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the flags as configurations in the pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

[Reference Site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/howto.html)